# footprint in rviz issue

Tags: ros, rviz, footprint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,everyone,

How can the footprint be displayed in the rviz? In the old ROS version,there may be a *local_costmap/robot_footprint* topic published by *move_base* node. But in the indigo version there is no *local_costmap/robot_footprint* topic(all topic published by move_base is as below), so how can the footprint be displayed in the rviz?

```
  Node [/move_base]
Publications: 
 * /move_base/global_costmap/costmap_updates [map_msgs/OccupancyGridUpdate]
 * /move_base/current_goal [geometry_msgs/PoseStamped]
 * /move_base/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription]
 * /move_base/local_costmap/inflation_layer/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription]
 * /move_base/feedback [move_base_msgs/MoveBaseActionFeedback]
 * /move_base/result [move_base_msgs/MoveBaseActionResult]
 * /move_base/global_costmap/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config]
 * /move_base/local_costmap/costmap [nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid]
 * /move_base/global_costmap/static_layer/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config]
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer_footprint/footprint_stamped [geometry_msgs/PolygonStamped]
 * /move_base/local_costmap/inflation_layer/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config]
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer_footprint/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config]
 * /move_base/global_costmap/static_layer/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription]
 * /move_base/local_costmap/costmap_updates [map_msgs/OccupancyGridUpdate]
 * /move_base/NavfnROS/plan [nav_msgs/Path]
 * /move_base/local_costmap/static_layer/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config]
 * /move_base/local_costmap/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription]
 * /move_base/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config]
 * /move_base/status [actionlib_msgs/GoalStatusArray]
 * /move_base/global_costmap/inflation_layer/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config]
 * /move_base/global_costmap/costmap [nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid]
 * /cmd_vel [geometry_msgs/Twist]
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer_footprint/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription]
 * /move_base/local_costmap/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config]
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config]
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer_footprint/footprint_stamped [geometry_msgs/PolygonStamped]
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription]
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription]
 * /move_base/goal [move_base_msgs/MoveBaseActionGoal]
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/local_plan [nav_msgs/Path]
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/cost_cloud [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2]
 * /move_base/global_costmap/inflation_layer/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription]
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription]
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config]
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer_footprint/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription]
 * /move_base/local_costmap/static_layer/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription]
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/global_plan [nav_msgs/Path]
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer_footprint/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config]
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config]
 * /move_base/global_costmap/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription]

Subscriptions: 
 * /move_base/local_costmap/footprint [unknown type]
 * /tf [tf2_msgs/TFMessage]
 * /odom [nav_msgs/Odometry]
 * /scan [sensor_msgs/LaserScan]
 * /move_base_simple/goal [geometry_msgs/PoseStamped]
 * /tf_static [unknown type]
 * /map [nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid]
 * /move_base/global_costmap/footprint [unknown type]
 * /move_base/goal [move_base_msgs/MoveBaseActionGoal]
 * /move_base/cancel [unknown type]

Services: 
 * /move_base/global_costmap/static_layer/set_parameters
 * /move_base/set_parameters
 * /move_base/local_costmap/set_parameters
 * /move_base/get_loggers
 * /move_base/NavfnROS/make_plan
 * /move_base/make_plan
 * /move_base/local_costmap/static_layer/set_parameters
 * /move_base/set_logger_level
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer/set_parameters
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer_footprint/set_parameters
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/set_parameters
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer_footprint/set_parameters
 * /move_base/global_costmap/inflation_layer/set_parameters
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/set_parameters
 * /move_base/clear_costmaps
 * /move_base/global_costmap/set_parameters
 * /move_base/local_costmap/inflation_layer/set_parameters
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216152/footprint-in-rviz-issue/) by [redskydeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22936/redskydeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2015-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If what you asked is robot footprint, yes, you should add `geometry_msgs/PolygonStamped` and subscribe to `local_costmap/robot_footprint` topic.

By the way, please add updates to your original post by editing, not as an answer. Also if you have a new question you can ask separately.

**UPDATE**

For Indigo, yes, you can subscribe to `/move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer_footprint/footprint_stamped` for visualization in RViz. Type is again `geometry_msgs/PolygonStamped`

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [redskydeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22936/redskydeng/) on 2015-08-20**:
UnfoX,

Thanks for your advice!

There is no *local_costmap/footprint* published by *move_base* node in the indigo ROS,but the *move_base* subscripts a */move_base/local_costmap/footprint* topic. Is there any other topic should be run to publish the */move_base/local_costmap/footprint* topic?